# How to change background content when clicking in Navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, video, navbar

I am trying to create a website with a background video.
My idea is to put a background video as a banner, and every time the user changes category in the Navbar, the background video and the body content are changed.

So far, I have managed to make the video change using some slider buttons, but I don't really want them. I want the user to click on the Navbar and change the video automatically. If the user clicks on category 1, video 1 is shown, if he clicks on category 2, video 2 is shown and so on.

Can anybody help me with some ideas? I attach my HTML and JS:

```js
//MENU RESPONSIVE
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const navigation = document.querySelector(".navigation");

menuBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    menuBtn.classList.toggle("active");
    navigation.classList.toggle("active");
});

//Video Slider Nav
const btnsSlide = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-btn");
const slides = document.querySelectorAll(".video-slide");
const contents = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

let sliderNav = function (manual) {
    btnsSlide.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.classList.remove("active")
    });

   slides.forEach((slide) => {
        slide.classList.remove("active")
    });

    contents.forEach((content) => {
        content.classList.remove("active")
    });

    btnsSlide[manual].classList.add("active");
    slides[manual].classList.add("active");
    contents[manual].classList.add("active");
}

btnsSlide.forEach((btn, i) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        sliderNav(i);
    })
});

inicio.forEach((btn, i) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        sliderNav(i);
    })
});
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Website</title>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f17ab486c8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <a href="#" class="brand"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" width="30%"></a>
        <div class="menu-btn"></div>
        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="navigation-items">
                <a href="#">Category 1</a>
                <a href="#">Category 2</a>
                <a href="#">Category 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section class="home" id="home">
        <video class="video-slide active" src="img/01.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
        <video class="video-slide active" src="img/02.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
        <video class="video-slide" src="img/03.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
        <div class="content active">
            <h1>Title<br><span>1</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos veniam labore consequatur, ab perferendis
                vero aliquid provident temporibus eius, iste optio. Quia aliquam temporibus obcaecati perferendis,
                voluptatem necessitatibus accusamus ipsum.</p>
            <a href="#">Learn more</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <h1>Title<br><span>2</span></h1>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos veniam labore consequatur, ab perferendis
                vero aliquid provident temporibus eius, iste optio. Quia aliquam temporibus obcaecati perferendis,
                voluptatem necessitatibus accusamus ipsum.</p>
            <a href="#">Read More</a>
        </div>
            <div class="slider-navigation">
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
            <div class="nav-btn"></div>
        </div>


    </section>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of having several video elements, you could dynamically change the video `src` tag based on the nav link the user clicks.

Comment: Agreed, just hide with css, load a new src and show again. Also, this is not really a question, you're asking for a code.